# How to unmarshal XML valid part of not xml file - JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have to marshal some class in XML format to the file (with no xml extension) as a header, and then append at the end of a file some invalid content. After that, obviously I would like to unmarshal this class with a JAXB unmarshaller, but I got a problem - it returns null, because the file is no longer valid xml (without additional content, all works perfect).

My file looks like:

```
<Root>
    <Element>
         ...
    </Element>
    ...
</Root>
[binary invalid content]
```

Is that possible to unmarshal only xml valid part of a file? 
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Have you tried "cutting" the filecontent you provide to JAXB after the closing root element?

Comment: I need to unmarshall class (xml header) before I read the file content, because there are (in this class) parameters how to do it. I can't do it first and trim the file to make it xml valid, because it's too large to keep it in the memory (that's assumption) and only when I unmarshall this class first I can start to read the content. Of course, I can rewrite <Root> to another, temporary file, and then umarshall it easily, but I would like to find something smarter.

Comment: And it really **has to** be one single file? A container like ZIP for an xml and a bin file would not be an alternative? I have the feeling you are making yourself a harder time than it is neccessary ...